# KVO and MVC Question

Tags: objective-c

Simple question here... Is it alright in terms of MVC design to observe a value in the model from a view (using Key-Value observing), and update the view's current location on the screen based on when the model's variable changes?

Is it okay to observe from the view object and have that object move itself when the Location variable inside of the model object changes?

Or is this against MVC because the view and the model are communicating in a sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should tie it through a C, **controller**, item.  Even if it means you're pulling in the state data from the model, and then having the controller set the view or the view read that data from the Controller.

The view and model should always be separated by a controller.  That's MVC according to Apple.  The reason is that even right now it may be straightforward for you to have the view reference the model's state - but the model could change in the future, and then you'd be stuck updating the view, when there's really no reason the view should be impacted.  And the model should never update the view's position - it should really not have any idea of any details of display.  That's the job of a controller, to **control** your views and move them around based on model data.

Think about it this way: the view should only know how to display things or interact with user I/O, a model should only know about the business logic with data that comes in over an interface of inputs and outputs.  You should be able to run a model without a view even existing, instead you should be able to just have unit test type code that feeds those inputs and outputs.  So something like moving a view around is completely out of the responsibilities of a model.

Comment: okay I understand. In my app I have a MutableArray of Balloons.. I have 2 different classes Balloon (the model) and BalloonV (the view).. If i use KVO on the model's variables from the controller, what's a good way to go about linking the correct model objects with their corresponding views? I have two arrays, one for models, one for views.. would I just have the corresponding model/view pair share the same index in their corresponding arrays, so that I could move the correct view, and know which view I should move based on which model's variable changed.

Comment: @Dalisto1 Hi, let's say your BalloonV view takes an input @"Green" or such for a color of a balloon to display within an NSView.  And let's say Balloon model also outputs @"Green" or such for a color representing it's balloon.  In this case, BalloonV should NOT observe keys of Balloon changing.  You should add BalloonController to do that. An advantage is that BalloonController will know about ALL Balloons on your model, and ALL BalloonViews being displayed. It may know more, like position data that it computes itself or pulls from a physics model or something.  Hope that helps